# How can I pass multiple implementations of a generic (which must also conform to a protocol) into my Model struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I'm trying to learn iOS development by following along with an open-access online Stanford course from 2021 (CS193p). The [assignment](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/sites/g/files/sbiybj16636/files/media/file/assignment_3_0.pdf) I'm trying to complete is to develop a single player version of the card game ["Set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)).

A traditional game of Set requires that a card has **four Characteristics**, which can each take on **three variations**. In my specific case, the ViewModel will be passing in the following Characteristics:

1. The shapes on the cards
2. Their color
3. Their shading
4. How many shapes there are on the card (1-3)

My current approach has a `SetGame` Model with a `Card` struct that has four `Characteristic`s. Because I want the `SetGame` struct to be reusable (for the sake of learning MVVM design principles), I want the `Characteristic`s to be a general type. I want the game's logic to work regardless of what `Characteristic`s the ViewModel passes it.
I want each implementation of the generic `Characteristic` to have three and only three variants, so I thought I'd need to use a protocol as well.

How can I pass in these `Characteristic`s from my ViewModel class?

**Model**

```swift
import Foundation
 
struct SetGame<Characteristic: HasThreeVariations> { // Is this okay? 
    private var cardArray: Array<Card>
   
    struct Card {
        let characteristic1: Characteristic
        let characteristic2: Characteristic
        let characteristic3: Characteristic
        let characteristic4: Characteristic
    }
 
    // Game logic here
}
 
protocol HasThreeVariations {
    associatedtype Variant
    var variant1: Variant { get }
    var variant2: Variant { get }
    var variant3: Variant { get }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```swift
class SSNCSetGame: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var model: SetGame<???> // What to put here?
   
    // ...

    struct ShapeCount: HasThreeVariations {
        typealias Variant = NumberOfShapes
        var variant1 = NumberOfShapes.one
        var variant2 = NumberOfShapes.two
        var variant3 = NumberOfShapes.three
    }
    enum NumberOfShapes {
        case one, two, three
    }
   
    struct ShapeColor: HasThreeVariations {
        typealias Variant = ColorOfShape
        var variant1 = ColorOfShape.red
        var variant2 = ColorOfShape.green
        var variant3 = ColorOfShape.blue
    }
    enum ColorOfShape {
        case red, green, blue
    }
 
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to check out [ask]. Right now, you have multiple questions (some of which are opinion-based) and the question will likely get closed as off-topic because of this.

Comment: I'd suggest that your question "is this the most elegant..." is still opinion based. The second part of it ("is there a more powerful way of doing this") may be a good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as well a couple minutes after my edit, I've just been working on what I want to say exactly. Thanks again for helping out a newcomer!!

Comment: You can't really learn MVVM via SwiftUI because the view layer is automatically generated (by it diffing our declarative `View` data structs and using the different to init/update/deinit UIView objects) and we have no access to it (some have tried via introspection). You could try in UIKit but it already has a pattern called child view controllers and a responder chain that already does what MVVM attempts to achieve and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the compiler that SSNCGameSet will have a `SetGame` of type `T` like this:

```
class SSNCSetGame<T : HasThreeVariations>: ObservableObject {
    init(model: SetGame<T>) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    @Published private var model: SetGame<T>
```

Then, it will be typed to the appropriate generic at compile type from the call site.